# Limit on number of kernel arguments in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I wanted to know if there is any limit on the number of arguments that are set to kernel function in OpenCL. I am getting the error as INVALID_ARG_INDEX while setting arguments. I am setting 9 arguments in the kernel function. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Can you post your kernel prototype please?

Comment: The OpenCL Work Group regularly visits the official OpenCL forums on the Khronos website. If no one here is able to give you an accurate answer, perhaps trying in the OpenCL forums would be beneficial. Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems way too low. Can you link to the code or paste it here?

Answer (score 9):

You might try calling the following function: [www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html)

The only argument limits seem to concern:
-CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS (arguments which are pointers to the __constant memory space)
-CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS
-CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS

Max read image arguments count should not be a problem, however max constant arguments count and max write image arguments count should be at least 8 on all devices. I might be that you are passing 9 write images on a device that only accepts 8, for example...